# Three.js - If sphere intercepts element, change color

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating a project in `Three.js` where whenever the user's mouse intersects a face of a tessellated surface, it turns red. I want to extend this to the whole `sphere`, which means that whenever a point of the sphere meets the centroid of a face, it should turn red.

This is the formula used to calculate the centroid of an `intersected face`:

```
INTERSECTED = intersects[0];
var intGeometry = INTERSECTED.object.geometry;
var intFace     = INTERSECTED.face;    

var intVertices = intGeometry.vertices;
var v1 = intVertices[intFace.a],
    v2 = intVertices[intFace.a],
    v3 = intVertices[intFace.a];

var intPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
intPosition.x = (v1.x + v2.x + v3.x) / 3;
intPosition.y = (v1.y + v2.y + v3.y) / 3;
intPosition.z = 0;
```

And this is the one is use for the `sphere`, which is equal to the mouse position:

```
var pos = camera.position.clone().add(dir.multiplyScalar(distance));
mouseMesh.position.copy(pos);
```

I think that the best way to approach it the issue, is to fetch over all of the faces of the Mesh and if the distance among each centroid is less than the `sphere Radius`, then make it red. But apparently, I am not able to collect all the faces of `backgroundMesh`.

Do you know how to solve this issue? This is the [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vex6fdd5/) with the whole code.

Thanks in advance for your replies!

**EDIT**

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6g28sqba/), with a possible solution.